# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'B' was corrupted

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, matrix-inverse

this error keeps coming up yet i dont see a problem with the code (its in c++)
the program is supposed to find the inverse of a 2x2 matrix

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
    float d;
    float A[2][2], B[2][2];

    do {
        cout << "please enter valid parameters in for 11,12,21,22" << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                cin >> A[i][j];
        }

        d = (A[1][1] * A[2][2]) - (A[1][2] * A[2][1]);
    } while(d == 0);

    B[1][1] = A[2][2] * (1.0 / d);
    B[1][2] = A[1][2] * (-1.0 / d);
    B[2][1] = A[2][1] * (-1.0 / d);
    B[2][2] = A[1][1] * (1.0 / d);

    for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        for(int h = 0; h < 2; h++) 
            cout << B[k][h] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are indexing B and A from 1 to 2 , instead use it from 0 to 1.